# Windows Forms: simulate holding key down on keyboard

Tags: c#, winforms

During my search, I've seen many different versions of this question, yet somehow none of the solutions provided solved my problem.
It's really quite simple, I just want to simulate holding down a key on the keyboard through code. I want to try and make a character in a game walk forward constantly, so I just need to make a program that simulates holding down the 'W' key. I've seen a lot of people were using Windows Forms for this, I don't know if it actually is the right application but if it works I'm happy.

Just very quickly sending the key doesn't work, so simply calling SendKeys.Send('W') every 30ms does not make my character move in-game. So, what can I do to simulate holding down a key on the keyboard?

Comment: This "game" is an external process, correct? And how do you have that game hooked? A `Process`?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, a .Net library can simulate key press
https://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/

**Edit**

To get the key works, the external program must in active window, and your program need to run in background.

> Windows Forms provides the SendKeys method which can simulate text
> entry, but not actual key strokes. Windows Input Simulator can be used
> in WPF, Windows Forms and Console Applications to synthesize or
> simulate any Keyboard input including Control, Alt, Shift, Tab, Enter,
> Space, Backspace, the Windows Key, Caps Lock, Num Lock, Scroll Lock,
> Volume Up/Down and Mute, Web, Mail, Search, Favorites, Function Keys,
> Back and Forward navigation keys, Programmable keys and any other key
> defined in the Virtual Key table.
>
> It provides a simple API to simulate
> text entry, key down, key up, key press and complex modified key
> strokes and chords.